# useTranslation causing empty pages and no error display in console

Tags: javascript, i18next, react-i18next

When i added useTranslation in the code, things just went wrong, and i don't know why.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
```

```
export default function SignIn() {

  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const submitBtn = () => {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.account);
    console.log(user.password);
    if (user.account === undefined) {
      console.log("Account is undefined");
      setAccountTip({ color: true, text: "Please Fill Account Column" });
      return;
    } else {
      setAccountTip("");
    }
    if (user.password === undefined) {
      console.log("Password is undefined");
      setPasswordTip({ color: true, text: "Please Fill Password Column" });
      return;
    } else {
      setPasswordTip("");
    }
    fetchData('/api/login', user, 'POST').then(response => {
      let status = response.status;
      console.log('status= ' + status + ' document cookie = ' + document.cookie);
      if (status === 200) {
        let token = assistant.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
        console.log(`status=${status}, token= ${token}`);
        // window.location.href = `/admin/dashboard`;
        // return <Redirect to="/admin/dashboard" />;
        
      } else {
        alert(`status : ${status} , Login Failure`);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
        dispatch(slice.actions.setRoles(r.allroles));
        dispatch(slice.actions.setConfigParams(r.allParams));
        const path = r.firstPage;
        if(path)
          history.push(`/admin${path}`) 
          // window.location.href = `/admin${path}`;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert('Login Failure');
    });
  }
```

In this code i'm not adding it into the translation area yet but the pages is already blank.

Want a solution to let the hook work.